# Footer not shown, when child page listing

Tags: wordpress

I created a custom page template and put these "child page listing with thumbnail" code 
footer not showing when I use this code.

```
  <!------------------section-container------------------>
 <div id="section-container">
 <?php
 $pages = get_pages('child_of='.$post->ID.'&parent='.$post->ID.'&sort_column
  =menu_order&sort_order=asc');
   foreach($pages as $page)
  { ?>
    <div class="section-page">
  <div class="section-thumb"><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($page->ID) ?>" title="                            
   <?php echo $page->post_title ?>">
   <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(150,100)); ?></a>
   </div>
   </div><!--section-text-->
    </div><!--section-page-->
   <?php } ?>
   </div>
     <!------------------section-container------------------>
```

Example : http://www.behance.in/our-work/

Answer (score 0):

Have you also included `<?php get_footer(); ?>` on your custom template?

Maybe you pasted over it when you included your custom code?

Wordpress templates need to explicitly call get_header, get_sidebar and get_footer if you want to include header.php, sidebar.php and footer.php.

Comment: yes here are codes after above code
       <div class="clearboth"></div>

       <?php the_content(); ?>
           <?php edit_post_link('Edit', '', ''); ?>
    </div><!--end entry-->
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
 <p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
   <!--do not delete-->
   <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!-- end content -->
   
         <?php get_sidebar(); ?>   
  
  </div><!--end main-->
 
<?php get_footer();  ?>

Comment: Looks like it's all fixed now, footer present & <html> tag is closed properly